# Structure to store and retrieve date information between two specific dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have events that have occurred on specific dates e.g:

```
[{'date_event': datetime.date(2001, 1, 1), 'event_name': 'event_1'},
 {'date_event': datetime.date(2001, 10, 1), 'event_name': 'event_2'}]
```

I am looking for a data structure in Python to store this information in such a way that I can easily retrieve events that occur between specific dates. In essence, I want to be able to query a data structure and return events that occurred between two dates. e.g.:

```
 def return_events_between_dates(start_date, end_date):
     ...
     return(list_of_events)
```

Is there a builtin structure in Python which easily allows this? I am not looking to re-invent the wheel if there is already something which is optimized for this sort of query. If not, would list-comprehension be the best approach?

Comment: From where you want to retrieve data, that must be allow you date comparison, like if you use `DJango` date field, then it will allow date comparison

Comment: @DanGetz - thanks - yeh, that was what i meant - and thanks for the answer - this is was exactly the sort of thing i was hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No,** there's no simple built-in structure that would do this in an optimized way.

**However,** the standard library module [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) provides functions for working with sorted lists in a more optimized way than list comprehensions would. You can use this to accomplish your task; it just takes a little work and care.

Unfortunately, they don't take a key function as an argument, like `list.sort()` does. So to use the `bisect` functions you need to preprocess your event objects into things that are comparable, and will compare primarily based on their dates. Tuples can be nice for this:

```
preprocessed_events = [(e['date_event'], e['event_name']) for e in events]
preprocessed_events.sort()
```

Now you can use `bisect_left()` and `bisect_right()` to get the indices of your sorted list where the events you want begin and end (assuming your endpoints are both inclusive):

```
index_first = bisect.bisect_left(preprocessed_events, (start_date,))
index_last = bisect.bisect_right(preprocessed_events, (end_date,))
```

Note that you have to turn `start_date` and `end_date` into tuples to be comparable with the tuples in the sorted list.

Knowing the start and end indices, you can get a list of all the events with a slice of the sorted list, and if need be convert them back into whatever form you want to return them in.

Don't forget to check your slice indices, and your choices of `bisect_left()` and `bisect_right()`, to make sure you're including/excluding the endpoints you want to include/exclude. Especially in the case where you have multiple events on the same date as your `start_date` or `end_date`.